# How to modify url webview in setting screen?

Tags: android, webview

User have an activity with account & password (login screen). I have an activity is setting screen (using Webview), it depends on the url (model class Account have loginId & status).

I have a example: 
account.me/u/mobile/menuloginId={loginId}&from=android&status={1/2}

How to modify url and where is place modify url when login account?

Some code in class setting screen:

```
public class B2BSettingController extends B2BViewController implements OnClickListener {
public B2BWebView mWebView = null;
public B2BDialogWindow<String> logoutDialog = null;
private B2BWebViewDataLoading mDataLoadingDialogView;

B2BSettingController(B2BMainActivity act, B2BHandler handler) {
    super(act, handler);
}

@Override
public void displayContainView() {
    turnTo(R.layout.b2b_setting, false, null, false);
}

@Override
public void initView(Map<String, Object> bundle) {
    mDataLoadingDialogView = B2BWebViewDataLoading.getInstance(mActivity);
    showOtherTitle(this);
    B2BShowWitchButton btnStatus = new B2BShowWitchButton();
    btnStatus.isShowLogoutButton = true;
    showWhichButton(btnStatus);
    setTitle(R.string.setting_ok);
    mActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    mWebView = (B2BWebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.sv_setting);
    mWebView.setTag(this);
    mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

    mWebView.postUrl(MENU_PAGE, EncodingUtils.getBytes("loginId=" + B2BLoginBis.getUserLoginId()
            + "&contractType=" + B2BLoginBis.getUserContractType() + "&autoLoginKey="
            + B2BLoginBis.getUserAutoLoginKey() + "&lang=" + B2BApplication.getLanguage()
            + "&dpi=" + (mActivity.densityDpi >= 240 ? 1 : 0), "base64"));

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            if (errorCode == -2 && !mActivity.isDialogShowing()) {
                mActivity.showMessageDialog(mActivity.getString(R.string.no_network_connection));
            }
            mDataLoadingDialogView.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mDataLoadingDialogView.show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mDataLoadingDialogView.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks you!

Comment: Do you want to catch url when user log in from webview?

Comment: @ysfcyln excatly bro, how to do this?

Comment: please mark as correct answer if it works @Huy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method of `WebViewClient` to catch redirect url

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.equals(something)) {
                    // Do something
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                if (request.getUrl().toString().equals(something)) {
                    // Do something
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
```

Comment: i can't understand in "something", can u give me more details?

Comment: When you do action or go another page in webview, shouldOverrideUrlLoading triggered and gives you redirect url, you can use this url for your process for example status of login or opening another activity after checking url etc.